# Override parse function on Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection:

```
var user = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/user',

  parse: function (response) {
    return response.lunch;
    return response.dinner;
  }
});
```

which returns a json like this:

```
[ 
  {
lunch: [{
 appetizer : 'bagel',
 maincourse: 'steak',
 desert: 'sweets'
}]
},
{
dinner: [{
 appetizer : 'chips',
 main: 'rice',
 desert: 'sweets'
 }]
}
]
```

I want to combine both response.lunch and response.dinner and have a common collection: I tried:

```
parse: function (response) {
     var collection1 = response.lunch;
     var collection2 = response.dinner;
     return collection1.add(collection2.toJSON(), {silent : true});
   }
```

But it doesnot work. Also how do i do a each function to override all main with maincourse? I tried:

```
this.collection.each(function(model) {
  var a = model.get("main");
  model.set({a: "maincourse"});
   }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to merge `lunch` and `dinner` so that your collection ends up with `{ appetizer : 'bagel', ... }` and `{ appetizer : 'chips', ... }` inside it. If so, then simply [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the two arrays together:

```
parse: function(response) {
    return response.lunch.concat(response.dinner);
}
```

If you want to rename all the `main` attributes to `maincourse` then you'd want to use [`get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) to pull out the `main`s, [`unset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-unset) to remove them, and then [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) to put them back in with the new name:

```
var maincourse = model.get('main');
model.unset('main', { silent: true });
model.set('maincourse', maincourse, { silent: true });
```

or just edit `attributes` directly:

```
model.attributes.maincourse = model.attributes.main;
delete model.attributes.main;
```

or better, just rename the attribute in your `parse` method.